# Android Studio can not find android-support-V7

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

Error:

```
E:\tmp\xxx\PullToRefresh\src\com\handmark\pulltorefresh\library\PullToRefreshRecyclerView.java:55: error: can not access ScrollingView
        recyclerView.setId(R.id.recyclerview);
                    ^
  can not access android.support.v4.view.ScrollingView 
E:\tmp\xxx\PullToRefresh\src\com\handmark\pulltorefresh\library\PullToRefreshRecyclerView.java:61: error: can not access NestedScrollingChild
        if (mRefreshableView.getChildCount() <= 0)
                            ^
  con not find android.support.v4.view.NestedScrollingChild
```

My project information:
Android Studio workspace:

1. Project A dependence Project B and C;
2. Project B dependence Project C;

Project B's build.gradle
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
//    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'
    compile project(':Recyclerview')
}
```

Poject C's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
}
```

The root reason:
Project C use the jar of com.android.support:recyclerview-v7

but Project B has been use it in build.gradle as below:

```
compile project(':Recyclerview')
```

But I will get the error as above when I make project.

PS:
My OS is Windows 7
Android Studio version: 1.3.1

BTW, on my Ubuntu the same project everything is ok!

Comment: compile ("com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0")

Comment: I will get a error about more than one jar about com.android.support:recyclerview-v7 at project after I add the compile ("com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0")  to project B

Comment: Add this only C Section

Comment: @IntelliJ, It will get the more than one recycleview-v7 jar.

Comment: If I remove the local v7-jar, and only add the compile ("com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0") to project C, but project B still can not find the v7-jar's method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the solution**

```
dependencies {      

compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4' //by artifact name
        exclude group: 'com.android.support' //by group
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' //by both name and group

    }

}

// or below

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is what happens if the support library isn't up 2 date.

Open your sdk manager, and download the latest version of support Repository and Library. Within those 2 there are all compat/style/support libraries.

I assume your ubuntu installation is up 2 date.

[image]

Those 2 marked red, need to be up 2 date. I assume they arent on your windows based system.

Comment: Would you post some detail about your solution?

Comment: i have added an image of the sdk manager to clarify what i meant when i said you need to update support lib und repo

Comment: Thans every much!, I got the picture deatil, My Android SDK support has been installl all the repository and libarary in extras, it not relate the error.

Comment: sorry, thats just what went wrong, when my android studio wasnt able to find those libraries.